# PHP/JSON Array Output

Tags: php, arrays, charts, flot

I'm currently working to retrieve some data for which I want to use a FLOT line chart.

At present, this is how I am creating the array by getting data from the MYSQL database:

```
             $data = array("label" =>  $title);    

                while($row = $query->fetch()) {
                    $data['data'][] = array($row[3], $row[2]);
                }   

            $json = json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
            echo $json;
```

The above code output the following array (Based on the data from the Database):

```
    {"label":"hosting","data":[[2,"06\/07\/2014"],[7,"09\/07\/2014"]]}
```

This is what I want, however I need to somehow change the formatting of the array so that it is correctly formatted for the FLOT charts.

How would I got about changing the array from this:

```
    {"label":"hosting","data":[[2,"09\/07\/2014"],[2,"09\/07\/2014"]]}
```

To this:

```
    {label: 'hosting', data: [[2,09\/07\/2014], [2,09\/07\/2014]]}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? your expected output is invalid

Comment: The expected output is the way FLOT reads the array. For example, if i make a manual array and format it in that manner, FLOT reads it correctly and draws the line graph.

Comment: Are you sure?  thats not valid json.

Comment: Above one is valid json show in php while below one in java script.

Comment: 09\/07\/2014 isn't valid in javascript

Comment: why don't you just use the day?   {"label":"hosting","data":[[2,06],[7,09]]}

Comment: The issue isn't with the format of date. If i create that array manually directly in javascript, it works fine. The issues is that the json array needs to have the removal of the quotation marks (") as shown in my example.

Comment: Are you using JQuery?  you could do something like var obj = jQuery.parseJSON ( ' echo $json ' );

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON ( ' + <?php echo $json; ?> + ' );
</script>
```

Comment: This seems to be getting somewhere. It appears to now be adding the "Label" into the graph, however this section: array($row[3], $row[2]); is being converted to [object Object] in jQuery

Answer (score -1):

try doing this

```
$data = array(label =>  $title, data => array());    

     while($row = $query->fetch()) {
       $data[data][] = array($row[3], $row[2]);
     }
```

instead

```
$data = array("label" =>  $title);    

      while($row = $query->fetch()) {
          $data['data'][] = array($row[3], $row[2]);
      }
```